# Difference between a named Complex Type and an anonymous Complex Type in an Element

Tags: xml, wsdl, xsd

What is the difference between...

```
<xsd:element name=”add”>
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="x" type="xsd:float"/>
        <xsd:element name="y" type="xsd:float"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

and...

```
<xsd:complexType name=”add”>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="x" type="xsd:float"/>
        <xsd:element name="y" type="xsd:float"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Both would appear as:

```
<add>
    <x type="xsd:float">1.00</x>
    <y type="xsd:float">2.00</x>
</add>
```

In the SOAP envelope...so is there any definitive difference between the two definitions?

Comment: Is the element definition missing from the second schema fragment? You cannot possibly derive the instance document example from the second fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you should use element type if this document appear as root element in your SOAP envelope, and complexType type can't appear as root element they normally appear in child elements/not in root element.

Comment: Now that you say that I think I remember reading it in the spec, thanks =)

Comment: That being said, I am looking at a valid WSDL right now with complexTypes defined with a name attribute and not children of an Element direct under <schema>

Answer (score 7):

Defining an element that refers to a named complex type by name has exactly the same effect as putting the complex type inline within the element declaration - except that a named complex type can be re-used, for example in different element declarations or in other complex types derived by restriction or extension.